# How can I launch a job from user interface without waiting for the end of execution?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I using spring batch 3 to read some files and insert the data into a database, but I want to uncouple the process start from the user execution in order to allow the user do other things.

```
@Resource
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

Job importJobToProgress = queueJob.poll();

JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addDate("date", new Date())
            .toJobParameters();

jobLauncher.run(importJobToProgress, jobParameters);
```

I should use SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor or ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will do the job.  A `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is more production grade in that it won't allow an unlimited number of threads to be spawned.  `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` will blindly create new threads.